# Is it expensive to do trilinear texture mapping in a shader?

Tags: graphics, directx, rendering, shader, texture-mapping

Imagine a big procedural world that worths more than 300k triangles (about 5-10k per 8x8x8m chunk). Since it's procedural, I need to create all the data by code. I've managed to make a good normal smoothing algorithm, and now I'm going to use textures (everyone needs textures, you don't want to walk around simple-colored world, do you?). The problem is that I don't know where it's better to calculate UV sets on (I'm using *triplanar texture mapping*).
I have three approaches:
 **1.** Do calculations on **CPU**, then upload to the GPU (**mesh** is *not* being modified every frame - 90% of time it **stays static**, *calculations is done **per chunk** when chunk changes*);
 **2.** Do calculations on **GPU using vertex shader** (*calculations is done **for every triangle** in every frame*, but the meshes is kinda big - is it expensive to do so every frame?);
 **3.** Move the algorithm onto **OpenCL** (*calculations is done **per chunk** when chunk changes*, I already use OpenCL to do meshing of my data) and call the kernel when the mesh is being changed (inexpensive, but all my OpenCL experience is based on modifying existing code, but still I have some C background, so it may take a long time before I'll get it to work);

Which approach is better in respect that my little experiment is already little heavy for a mid-range hardware?

I'm using C# (.NET 4.0) with SlimDX and Cloo.

Comment: Did you read the following article? http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html It might be interesting for you, i've skimmed it and it looks like something similar :)

Comment: @Gnietschow Yes. I have absolutely no problems implementing triplanar mapping. I need to choose which approach (these three I've mentioned) will suit my application better. Seems like it's better to experiment with all three approaches to make a conslusion...